# Delete incomplete download from Play Store

Tags: google-play-store

I was downloading a game from Play Store, but suddenly errors occur when 75% file downloaded. My device storage is limited and now I wanted to delete that useless files.

Where are the files located?

Comment: Could you tell us about the error? What error message was it?

Comment: they are / get deleted, because most probably a checksum was wrong and so the download has failed. just try again.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to delete that. If an error occurs and download is interrupted the Android OS itself deletes that file(It consider it as garbage).

Answer (score 0):

You can also clear "Google Play Store" cache.

Comment: Hello. Can you mention the steps needed to do that?

Comment: It is according to the user interface of Samsung devices but it should be similar for other devices:
1- go to Setting
2-  select Apps
3- find "Google Play Store" and click on it
4-  select Storage
5- select CLEAR CACHE

Answer (score -1):

Try CleanMaster for Android. It tracks and deletes unwanted and useless files from the temp, obb and other folders. I have used it and works for me. Its easy ;)

Comment: A link for the app?

Comment: You know that Clean Master isn't generally liked by critics, right? Many sources of information are there that counter the fact that Clean Master actually does stuff. (http://www.quora.com/Is-the-Clean-Master-app-for-Android-really-useful) I've had a personal experience where I found out that it showed 3.6 gb as cleared space, when none of the files I had specified were actually cleaned. It's a bunch of fancy animations for me, nothing else.
Instead, go for a file browser like Solid Explorer and delete the files yourself.
Here's more proof : https://tr.im/7YYmZ

Comment: The app is available on Google Play.

Comment: @rjt.rockx - I am not supporting it for boosting the phone's performance. I agree the Android and Windows platforms are different. --- Even though there are some people criticizing the app, I have seen reduction in junk files and garbage from apps and it is also helpful to delete files that are useless on the phone. --- The rest depends on the user........ Anyways the files should automatically be deleted with the phone restarts, if not, then apps like these are easier than manually deleting something that should not be..